# Usage of weighting in pure SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

My front-end (SourcePawn) currently does the following:

```
float fPoints = 0.0;
float fWeight = 1.0;

while(results.FetchRow())
{
    fPoints += (results.FetchFloat(0) * fWeight);
    fWeight *= 0.95;
}
```

In case you don't understand this code, it goes through the resultset of this query:

```
SELECT points FROM table WHERE auth = 'authentication_id' AND points > 0.0 ORDER BY points DESC;
```

The resultset is floating numbers, sorted by `points` from high to low.

My front-end takes the 100% of the first row, then 95% of the second one, and it drops by 5% every time. It all adds up to `fPoints` that is my 'sum' variable.

What I'm looking for, is a solution of how to replicate this code in pure SQL and receive the sum which is called `fPoints` in my front-end, so I will be able to run it for a table that has over 10,000 rows, in one query instead of 10,000.

I'm very lost. I don't know where to start and guidance of any kind would be very nice.

Comment: Sample data and expected results would be helpful...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this using variables:

```
SELECT points,
       (points * (@f := 0.95 * @f) / 0.95) as fPoints
FROM table t CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT @f := 1.0) params
WHERE auth = 'authentication_id' AND points > 0.0
ORDER BY points DESC;
```

A note about the calculation.  The value of `@f` starts at 1.  Because we are dealing with variables, the assignment and the use of the variable need to be in the same expression -- MySQL does not guarantee the order of evaluation of expressions.

So, the `0.95 * @f` reduces the value by 5%.  However, that is for the *next* iteration.  The `/ 0.95` undoes that to get the right value for *this* iteration.

Comment: Thank you very much! Do you happen to know if this query will also work with SQLite?

Comment: @shavit . . . No.  SQLite does not support variables.  If you have a question about SQLite, ask it as *another* question.  The two databases are quite different.

Comment: Not really, I was just interested as my application should also support SQLite - which is fine because in this case I can use the fallback method I previously used!

Answer (score 1):

While I'm glad the answer [Gordon Linoff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1144035/gordon-linoff) provides works for you, you should understand it's quite specific.  `ORDER BY`, per the SQL standard, has no effect on *how* a query is processed, and SQL does not recognize "iteration" in a `SELECT` statement.  So the idea of "reducing a variable on each iteration", where the iteration order is governed by `ORDER BY` has no basis in standard SQL.  You might want to check if it's guaranteed by MySQL, just for your own edification.

To achieve the effect you want in a standard way, proceed as follows.

1. Create a table `Percentiles( Percentile int not null, Factor float not null )`
2. Populate that table with your factors (20 rows).
3. Write a view or CTE that [ranks your points](http://www.schemamania.org/sql/#rank.rows) in descending order.  Let us call the rank column `rank`.

Then join your view to Percentiles:

```
SELECT auth, sum(points * factor) as weight
FROM "your view" as t join percentiles as p
ON r.rank = percentile
WHERE points > 0.0 
GROUP BY auth
```

That query is simple, and its intent obvious.  It *might* even be faster.  Most important, it will definitely work, and doesn't depend on any idiosyncrasies of your current DBMS.

Comment: You have a rather strange answer, referring to a CTE for a dialect of SQL that doesn't support CTEs.  MySQL is pretty clear about the relationship between variable processing and `ORDER BY`.